Как определить, что в картинке большинство пикселей с одним значением?
Например, картинка почти или вся серая. Мне это нужно для того, чтобы отсекать неудачные скриншоты из видеопотока.
Потому что в нем иногда получаются именно такие скриншоты


Постройте гистограмму значений пикселов и проанализируйте их распределение.
Для абсолютно серого кадра гистограмма будет иметь один пик высотой в площадь кадра. Если небольшие различия есть, то смотрите ширину диапазона ненулевых значений. Иногда можно посчитать статистику распределения (например, среднеквадратичное отклонение)
